# How do I export a column of data in my Numbers sheet to a python list?

Tags: python, list, iteration, apple-numbers

There is a column of data in my Numbers sheet:
[image]

Is there a way to export it so that it becomes a list like this, which can be used in Python? I want to use this list for a loop:

```
['Antrostomus noctitherus','Tringa guttifer','xxx..','xxx..']
```

If there isn't, are there any other ways to export these data and use in a loop, maybe not making it into a list but something else instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it.

First, export this column into a CSV file which produce a comma-separated list:

```
Antrostomus noctitherus,Tringa guttifer,Pitta megarhyncha,Necrosyrtes monachus,Notiomystis cincta,Apteryx mantelli,Gallicolumba platenae,Aythya innotata
```

Then, add quotation marks on each end, which makes it a string value.

```
"Antrostomus noctitherus,Tringa guttifer,Pitta megarhyncha,Necrosyrtes monachus,Notiomystis cincta,Apteryx mantelli,Gallicolumba platenae,Aythya innotata"
```

Put in it python. Use the split() method and add pass ',' to the method, which means using the comma character as separator.

```
abc="Antrostomus noctitherus,Tringa guttifer,Pitta megarhyncha,Necrosyrtes monachus,Notiomystis cincta,Apteryx mantelli,Gallicolumba platenae,Aythya innotata"

birdNameList=abc.split(',')
```

The split method split the content around the comma, put them in string, and surround them with a square bracket. This makes it a list.

```
['Antrostomus noctitherus', 'Tringa guttifer', 'Pitta megarhyncha', 'Necrosyrtes monachus', 'Notiomystis cincta', 'Apteryx mantelli', 'Gallicolumba platenae', 'Aythya innotata']
```

I double-checked to make sure it's a list by running it in a for loop that prints each item out.